# For which ABIs I should compile my native code (Android API >= 21)?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, abi

My android app is compatible with android API >= 21. In it I use some C++ native code, but I'm not really sure for what platforms should I compile.

I guess that I need to compile for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86. Is that right? Is it necessary to support x86 for release build? Looks like all phones whick used that architecture, now is outdated.

Comment: Starting with NDK r17, some older / rarely used ABIs have been removed. So the ones that remain are `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, and `x86_64`. I don't have any figures on the number of devices per ABI / Android version. But you may be able to create one yourself through the Device Catalog section of the Google Play developer console.

Answer (score 1):

The Intel-based phones are exotic these days, see a detailed [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186334/what-percentage-of-android-devices-runs-on-x86-architecture) elsewhere on StackExchange. But if your app can be relevant for ChromeBook users, the x86_64 version would help.